# Mount filesystem from MacOS server on Windows

Tags: windows, network-share, mac-osx-server, file-sharing

I have a MacOS server with a large RAID attached to it, and I would like people with accounts on the server to be able to read and write to the server from a windows machine through the file explorer.

The windows machines can only connect to the server over the internet.

**How can I get a MacOS Server volume to be readable by windows machines over the internet?**

Comment: EEAA's alreadyy outlined one possible answer below; I would emphasize how important step 1 (and similar precautions like firewalling) is vs. having an SMB server open to the Internet.  Of course Windows fans that've been around long enough, will all remember how that goes :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a VPN for remote people to connect to.
2. Share the MacOS filesystem via smb (System Preferences->Sharing->File Sharing).
3. There is no step 3.